# Disable editing between specified tags in CkEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

As ur experience, there are any way to do that?
For example, i have a default layout, which loads when the user starts editing an empty document, something like this:

```
<h1>Sample heading</h1>
<p>Sample text</p>
<div class="something"></div>
```

Here, i want to have a control to prevent ppl starting to writing into the .something div. 
If possible, i want to disable the possibility to remove my predefined tags too.

Sorry for english, and thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 3):

For others finding this via search engines.

You can use the contenteditable attribute of HTML within a CKEditor document.

http://docs.cksource.com/CKeditor_3.x/Users_Guide/NonEditable_Contents

Comment: This will work for preventing editing _within_ the `.something` div, but unfortunately does not prevent _removing_ said element if it's inside another `contenteditable=true` element. Even within the page you linked, it admits that in every browser except Firefox the element gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

First solution that i can think of is to hook all possible events that manipulate content, create document tree location aware logic and simply intercept and counter events which would edit areas described by your requirements as non-editable.

And im most curious if there is something easier then that.

Comment: It's the only solution I've found that works so far, unfortunately.